# Selenium finds element on a page but not on another

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to get the location for sotre from google maps but my code sometimes gets it for a store and sometimes it doesnt get it for another. here the link to the google colab

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ncrffQMGyeudUkMiGSrCfssifVScfYa-?usp=sharing

you can see in the end that it gets it for "blaze" and not for "apple" or "ferrari"

why and how can this be?

NOTE: it is NOT about the page having to load, i made it wait up until 20 seconds and it still does not work.

i expect to get the location for each link i give it to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each page has different page structure, so you need to point the element using a relative xpath. So, change this line

```
location = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div[3]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text
```

with this one

```
location = driver.find_element('xpath','//button[@data-item-id="address"]').text
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using Xpath to find your element, so depending on the structure of the page it could change.
I have completed some test with your data using BeautifulSoup library with Selenium.

I think it is more reliable to find address with CSS Selector.
To help you, consider this documentation :
https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors

try this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


blaze = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Blaze+Pizza/@24.5014283,54.3896917,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5e676982d20b17:0xe2c5b69e67e4c85d!8m2!3d24.5014283!4d54.3896917'
apple = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Apple+Yas+Mall/@24.4881123,54.6064438,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5e457d92f94e27:0x5c1646b499917d03!8m2!3d24.4881123!4d54.6086325?authuser=0&hl=en'
ansam='https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ansam+Building+3/@24.4833165,54.6020795,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5e45db58e6a423:0x23953eb0c87dfd3c!8m2!3d24.4834477!4d54.5999224?authuser=0&hl=en'
ferrari='https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ferrari+World+Abu+Dhabi/@24.4836388,54.6059205,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5e457e2d394a05:0x6076df4876c470a9!8m2!3d24.4837634!4d54.6070066?authuser=0&hl=en'
yas='https://www.google.com/maps/place/Yass+winter+carnival/@24.4886382,54.6183841,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5e4f9134f9bac3:0x68162aeae1d91d21!8m2!3d24.4898629!4d54.6217851?authuser=0&hl=en'
yas1='https://www.google.com/maps/place/Yas+Links+Abu+Dhabi/@24.4756507,54.6019735,14.83z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5e4582ecaaecab:0xb3e0f29a13cc00d5!8m2!3d24.4783288!4d54.5999317?authuser=0&hl=en'

links = [blaze, apple, ansam, ferrari, yas, yas1]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)

def get_location(links):
    address_list = []
    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
        page_html= driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')
        address = soup.select_one('div.rogA2c div.fontBodyMedium').string
        address_list.append(address)
        time.sleep(5)
    return address_list
```

Best regards,

Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

absolute `xpath` is always fragile, instead use relative `xpath`

Instead of this

```
location = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div[3]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text
```

Try this

```
location = driver.find_element('xpath','(//div[@class="rogA2c"]//div[contains(@class,"fontBodyMedium")])[1]').text
```